# ggsave() recursively creating unwanted directories

Tags: ggplot2, tidyverse

I am using ggsave as following:

```
g = ggplot(<here>)
ggsave('./test/test/test.png',
       g,
       width = 5,
       height = 5,
       units = 'in',
       dpi = 300)
```

Where there is no directory called /test in my working directory. ggsave() has started creating these directories recursively since today (unsure why) and not throwing the usual warning that the directory does not exist.

Calling png() instead of ggsave() throws expected error and does not create directory.

```
png('./test/test/test.png)
g
dev.off()
```

I have updated ggplot2, restarted R session & RStudio. Tried in terminal external to RStudio.

I am running RStudio Desert Sunflower, R 4.2.3 and ggplot 3.4.4.
I can recreate on another machine running RStudio Desert Sunflower, R 4.2.2, and ggplot 3.4.2.

Any idea why this has just started happening?

Comment: Interesting. In fact, running `ggsave("test/test.png", plot = ggplot())` doesn't work, but other devices tested actually reproduce the described behaviour (I've tried with jpeg, tiff and png devices)

Comment: I feel that this is desired behaviour - but why it wouldn't work with default pdf device - no idea

Comment: FWIW, I've submitted a report. If it's desired or a bug - it will be interesting to hear what the package maintainer have to say! https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/5489

Comment: @tjebo thanks for following up and further testing. Will follow on GitHub to see what they say :)